# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable with function

Tags: python

New to coding and haven't encountered this type of return ant keep getting this error. I can only edit the 'f =' variable.

```
def a_plus_abs_b(a, b):
    """Return a+abs(b), but without calling abs.
    
    >>> a_plus_abs_b(2, 3)
    5
    >>> a_plus_abs_b(2, -3)
    5
    """
    if b < 0:
        f = (-1)*b + a
    else:
        f = (a+b)
    return f(a, b)
```

Comment: You want `return f`.   return f(a, b) is trying to call the function f with arguments a, b.  But, f is not a function but the value you calculated.  P.S.  This is more simpler done with `return a + abs(b)` which uses the abs function.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly return `f` in your function because it already holds the result of your calculation.

As for the `TypeError`, it just indicates that `int` can not be called like that, if not for type convert(e.g. `int(-3.5)`).

The corrected version:

```py
def a_plus_abs_b(a, b):
    """Return a+abs(b), but without calling abs.
    
    >>> a_plus_abs_b(2, 3)
    5
    >>> a_plus_abs_b(2, -3)
    5
    """
    if b < 0:
        f = (-1)*b + a
    else:
        f = (a+b)
    return f
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just immediately return the result of the addition instead of using `f=`. Since you are storing the result of the addition to the variable f, the line `return f(a,b)` results in an error because `f` is of the type `int`.

Example:

```
if b < 0:
    return (-1)*b + a
```